# Open Link in Email with IFTTT

Tags: gmail, if-this-then-that

Using [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com), I saw many recipes for getting an alert if a keyword or sender sends an email to your inbox, but I was hoping there would be a way to open any link found in the target email in my browser automatically.

I searched Google but came up empty handed. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Even if possible (and I don't think it is) this is a bad idea. Phishing attacks try to use social engineering to trick you into clicking a link. This would shortcut even that.

Comment: I'd be happy to explicitly set the domain name that the link would have to be from to prevent anything malicious.

Comment: Even so, IFTTT bridges the APIs of various online services (and a few smartphone hooks). There's nothing to open a Web browser. You'll need to find another tool for that (or build your own).